# Updating Model with more attributes (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a page containing a list `productListView` of images `productView`. `productListView` is binded to the collection `productList` containing models `product`. When an image is clicked, a modal `ModalView` appears containing more details about the product whose photo has been clicked on.

**Problem:** In order to minimize the data transferred to the user, only a few attributes of the products were `fetch`'ed when the page and `productListView` loaded. How should I update the model `product` with more attributese (like really long description) when its photo within `productListView` is clicked?

**Model**

```
Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/api/product'  // Gets FULL details of product
});
```

**Collection**

```
ProductCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/products'  // Gets MINIMAL details of product
})
```

**View**

```
ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#photo_list',

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(photo, index) {
            $(this.el).append(new ProductView({ model: photo }).render().el);
        }
        return this;
    },
});


ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagNAme: 'div',

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_ProductView').html() ),

    events: {
        'click .photo': 'showModal',
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    },

    // Creates the Modal View with FULL details of the product
    showModal: function() {
        modalView = new ModalView({ model: this.model });
    }
});
```

**Modal View**

```
ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#modal'),

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_modal').html() ),

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).show().append( this.template( this.model.toJSON( this.model ) ) );
    },

});
```

---

### UPDATE

I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'render'`. Why is this so even though I am using `_.bindAll` to bind `render`? I know `var self=this` will work, but why not the `_.bindAll`?

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    var self = this;
    // Update Model with Full details
    this.model.fetch({
        data: {post_id: this.model.get('id')},
        processData: true,
        success: function() {
            // The usual renders

            this.render();
        }
    });
```

Comment: fetch this.model in the initialize function of ModalView?

Comment: works! However I have another problem with calling `this.render()` from within the `fetch()`

Comment: Shouldn't you do `self.render();` within the body of the success callback?

Comment: `self.render()` works, but why doesn't `this.render()` work when I bind it using `_.bindAll(this, 'render');` as shown in the updated post?

Comment: The purpose of `_.bindAll()` is that, when `render` is called, `this` will be bound correctly within the body of the render function. It doesn't mean that any time `render` is called, the `this` attached to it is correct. To put it more clearly - `this.render()` is not guaranteed to be the correct `this`. But `render: function() { console.log(this); }` WILL be the correct `this`. Binding can only deal with the scope WITHIN the function, not AROUND it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok I get it! Cleared things up, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Product.fetch` call gets the full model (with the extended attributes) then change `showModal` to do just that and then render:

```
showModal: function() {
    var modalView = new ModalView({ model: this.model }),
        p = this.model.fetch();
    p.done(modalView.render);
}
```

and

```
ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#modal'),

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_modal').html() ),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.show().append( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    },

});
```

If fetch does not get you everything, then replace the fetch with the ajax call that does.

With regards to you update: `this` in the `success` callback context is the `window`. You want to use the saved `self` instead.

Comment: Is there any reason for doing the fetch and render in `showModal` and not in the `initialize` function of `ModalView`?

Comment: I never do render in initialize, as I might want to do most things inside initialize, or as is the case here, the model might not actually be ready after initialize.

Answer (score 1):

In this code, you should use `self.render();` instead of `this.render()`

```
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, 'render');
  var self = this;
  // Update Model with Full details

  this.model.fetch({
    data: {post_id: this.model.get('id')},
    processData: true,
    success: function() {
        // The usual renders
        self.render();
    }
});
```